# Why is my ng-show not working with <img>?

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, angularjs-ng-show

I can't get my ng-show to display an image based on the function's return. It should return a different image if it's true, false or null.

If you can't solve my problem could you just point me in the right direction as to how to do that?

If you can just look at the syntax in the html code I would be very grateful, it's throwing 25 errors in the chrome debug console:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=…%3D%3D%20'true'&p4=%7BisAttending(student.id%2Clesson.id)%20%3D%3D%20'true'
at angular.js:38
at s.throwError (angular.js:15090)
at s.object (angular.js:15079)
at s.primary (angular.js:14968)
at s.unary (angular.js:14956)
at s.multiplicative (angular.js:14943)
at s.additive (angular.js:14934)
at s.relational (angular.js:14925)
at s.equality (angular.js:14916)
at s.logicalAND (angular.js:14908) "<div ng-show="{{isAttending(student.id,lesson.id) == 'true'">"
```

It's the isAttending function, here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

<head>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overpass"
    rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="geisonApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div id="um"
        style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 60%; text-decoration: none; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 100;">
        <div>
            <ul id="dois">
                <li><a href="#"> <img
                        style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 16px; margin-top: -29px; margin-left: -25px;"
                        src="Untitled.png">
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CURSOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CALENDÁRIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GRUPOS DE DISCUSSÃO </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div style="float: right; margin-top: -71px;">
            <p style="position: relative; top: -10px; display: inline">Jaime
                Schettini</p>
            <img
                style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 16px; padding-right: 11px;"
                src="checked.png"> <img
                style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 16px; padding-right: 11px;"
                src="checked.png">

        </div>

    </div>
    <div
        style="background-color: #5cc8ec; width: 100%; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; height: 60px; font-family: arial; margin-top: -10px;">

        <span
            style="margin-left: 20% !important; margin-top: 25px; position: absolute; margin-left: 10px;">
            Matemática 6 Série - Frequência </span>

    </div>


    <br>

    <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 60%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td
                    style="width: 40%; border-top: 1px solid white; border-left: 1px solid white;">

                    <div
                        style="margin-left: 75%; margin-top: -2px; margin-bottom: -3px;">
                        <img src="play-button.png"
                            style="border: 1px solid #ebebeb; padding: 3px; margin-left: 17px;">
                        <img src="play-button.png"
                            style="border: 1px solid #ebebeb; padding: 3px; margin-left: -8px;">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="lesson in lessons">{{lesson.id}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 40%;"></td>
                <td ng-repeat="lesson in lessons"><img
                    style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 16px; padding-right: 11px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"
                    src="unchecked.png"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
                <td><img
                    style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 16px; padding-right: 11px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"
                    src="checked.png">
                    <p class="ng-binding"
                        style="display: inline; top: -23px; position: relative; font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: grey;">
                        {{student.name}}</p></td>

                <td ng-repeat="lesson in lessons">
                    <p>{{isAttending(student.id,lesson.id)}}</p>
                    <div ng-show="{{isAttending(student.id,lesson.id) == 'true'">
                        <img id="imgChecked" ng-src="checked.png">
                    </div>
                     <!--                           <img id="imgUnchecked" ng-show="{{isAttending(student.id,lesson.id)}} == 'false'"   ng-src="unchecked.png"> -->
                    <!--                            <img id="imgEmpty" ng-show="{{isAttending(student.id,lesson.id)}} == 'null'"    ng-src="empty.png"> -->

                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module("geisonApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

$scope.students = [ {
    "id" : 15,
    "username" : "jaime",
    "email" : "jaime",
    "name" : "Jaime",
    "photo" : null
}, {
    "id" : 31,
    "username" : "carol@gmail.com",
    "email" : "carol@gmail.com",
    "name" : "Carol",
    "photo" : null
}, {
    "id" : 48,
    "username" : "c@gmail.com",
    "email" : "c@gmail.com",
    "name" : "Cleberson Charles Colombo Faccin",
    "photo" : null
}, {
    "id" : 22840,
    "username" : "r@email.com",
    "email" : "r@email.com",
    "name" : "Rodrigo",
    "photo" : null
}, {
    "id" : 29020,
    "username" : "c@email.com",
    "email" : null,
    "name" : "Caio",
    "photo" : null
} ];

$scope.lessons = [ {
    "id" : 59,
    "startDate" : 1456826400000,
    "endDate" : 1456830000000
}, {
    "id" : 60,
    "startDate" : 1456999200000,
    "endDate" : 1457002800000
}, {
    "id" : 61,
    "startDate" : 1457431200000,
    "endDate" : 1457434800000
}, {
    "id" : 62,
    "startDate" : 1457604000000,
    "endDate" : 1457607600000
}, {
    "id" : 63,
    "startDate" : 1458036000000,
    "endDate" : 1458039600000
} ];

$scope.attendances = [ {
    "id" : 6,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 58
    },
    "present" : true,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 15
    }
}, {
    "id" : 819368,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 59
    },
    "present" : true,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 15
    }
}, {
    "id" : 819367,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 59
    },
    "present" : true,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 48
    }
}, {
    "id" : 967272,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 62
    },
    "present" : null,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 15
    }
}, {
    "id" : 967273,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 62
    },
    "present" : null,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 31
    }
}, {
    "id" : 967274,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 62
    },
    "present" : null,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 48
    }
}, {
    "id" : 967275,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 62
    },
    "present" : false,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 22840
    }
}, {
    "id" : 967276,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 62
    },
    "present" : null,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 29020
    }
}, {
    "id" : 4,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 63
    },
    "present" : true,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 15
    }
}, {
    "id" : 5,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 64
    },
    "present" : false,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 15
    }
}, {
    "id" : 16,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 65
    },
    "present" : true,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 15
    }
}, {
    "id" : 17,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 66
    },
    "present" : false,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 15
    }
}, {
    "id" : 967232,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 66
    },
    "present" : true,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 29020
    }
}, {
    "id" : 664012,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 67
    },
    "present" : true,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 15
    }
}, {
    "id" : 664013,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 67
    },
    "present" : true,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 31
    }
}, {
    "id" : 664014,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 67
    },
    "present" : true,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 48
    }
}, {
    "id" : 664015,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 67
    },
    "present" : true,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 22840
    }
}, {
    "id" : 664016,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 67
    },
    "present" : true,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 29020
    }
}, {
    "id" : 664007,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 68
    },
    "present" : false,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 15
    }
}, {
    "id" : 664008,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 68
    },
    "present" : false,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 31
    }
}, {
    "id" : 664009,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 68
    },
    "present" : false,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 48
    }
}, {
    "id" : 664010,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 68
    },
    "present" : false,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 22840
    }
}, {
    "id" : 664011,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 68
    },
    "present" : false,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 29020
    }
}, {
    "id" : 305303,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 90
    },
    "present" : false,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 15
    }
}, {
    "id" : 305302,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 90
    },
    "present" : false,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 31
    }
}, {
    "id" : 305306,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 90
    },
    "present" : false,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 22840
    }
}, {
    "id" : 305307,
    "lesson" : {
        "id" : 90
    },
    "present" : false,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 29020
    }
} ];

$scope.isAttending = function(studentId, lessonId) {
    var coisa;
    $scope.attendances.forEach( function(arrayItem){
        if(arrayItem.lesson.id === lessonId){
            if(arrayItem.user.id === studentId){
             //                 console.log(arrayItem.user.id + "-" + arrayItem.lesson.id +" = " + arrayItem.present);
                coisa = arrayItem.present;
            }
        }
    });
    return coisa;

     //     return studentId + "-" + lessonId;
} 
});
```

CSS:

```
    body {
   margin:0;
}

div#um{
    background-color: white;
}

ul#dois {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 8px;
}


li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

table{
   border-collapse: collapse;
   width: 100%;
}

th {
    height: 50px;
}

img#imgUnchecked, #imgChecked{
    padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 16px; padding-right: 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the error, the last line shows your mistake.
When you use an angular tag like **ng**-show you dont have to use the curly braces **{{**

Remove the curly braces and it should work fine

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo in

```
<div ng-show="isAttending(student.id,lesson.id)">
```

That is cause the error in the angular log see last line

the `isAttending` function should return true if you want the img to be visible